# Dictionary to Pandas Dataframe without un-nesting some values

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below dictionary, and I only want the columns to be key, metric and collectionperiod. These columns can have nested values which I would leave for now and un-nest later. But for some reason the values in the dataframe look off.

```
{'key': {'formFactor': 'PHONE', 'origin': 'https://www.sample'},
 'metrics': {'cumulative_layout_shift': {'histogram': [{'start': '0.00',
     'end': '0.10',
     'density': 0.7861256879559706},
    {'start': '0.10', 'end': '0.25', 'density': 123},
    {'start': '0.25', 'density': 111}],
   'percentiles': {'p75': '0.07'}},
  'experimental_interaction_to_next_paint': {'histogram': [{'start': 0,
     'end': 200,
     'density': 0.5416453755748598},
    {'start': 200, 'end': 500, 'density': 1},
    {'start': 500, 'density': 23}],
   'percentiles': {'p75': 504}},
  'experimental_time_to_first_byte': {'histogram': [{'start': 0,
     'end': 800,
     'density': 123},
    {'start': 800, 'end': 1800, 'density': 123},
    {'start': 1800, 'density': 23}],
   'percentiles': {'p75': 877}},
  'first_contentful_paint': {'histogram': [{'start': 0,
     'end': 1800,
     'density': 22},
    {'start': 1800, 'end': 3000, 'density': 664},
    {'start': 3000, 'density': 67}],
   'percentiles': {'p75': 1662}},
  'first_input_delay': {'histogram': [{'start': 0,
     'end': 100,
     'density': 234},
    {'start': 100, 'end': 300, 'density': 44},
    {'start': 300, 'density': 555}],
   'percentiles': {'p75': 34}},
  'largest_contentful_paint': {'histogram': [{'start': 0,
     'end': 2500,
     'density': 0.7725250984877367},
    {'start': 2500, 'end': 4000, 'density': 777},
    {'start': 4000, 'density': 544}],
   'percentiles': {'p75': 2352}}},
 'collectionPeriod': {'firstDate': {'year': 2022, 'month': 10, 'day': 14},
  'lastDate': {'year': 2022, 'month': 11, 'day': 10}}}
```

When I add the above `res` to the code below, there seems to be an index column that is actually the 'key' nested values, but I don't want them like that. The dataframe should only have 1 row:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(res, orient ='columns')
df
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the format of the data, consider using [pd.DataFrame.from_dict()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html#pandas.DataFrame.from_dict) which outputs the desired format:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([res])
```

Comment: This still doesn't show it as 1 row but rather multiple rows. I found this to work but I'm not entirely sure why: df = pd.DataFrame([res], columns=res.keys())

Comment: Thanks I have also edited my answer to include another option

Comment: Thanks Celius - can you explain why I need to add my dictionary into brackets, I'm unsure why this works? So I know for future use